# Can nonlinear functions be added between two weight matrices?

Tags: deep-learning, nonlinear-functions

Can one hidden layer consists of two weight matrices with an element-wise nonlinear function in between?

Comment: Generally, no, the layer represents the matrix multiplication. But the term layer is used loosely

Comment: Hi~ thanks, I read this paper, arxiv.org/pdf/1710.06234.pdf and in Figure 1 bottom branch, the author constructs one layer with $W_1 \rho W_2$ where $W_1$ and $W_2$ are weight matrices and $\rho$ inbetween is element-wise nonlinear function.